# Can't the item.text be assigned to a String in a Android Studio sample code?

Tags: android, kotlin

The following sample code from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste

It seems that there are some errors with the sample code, I have to replace `pasteData = item.text` with `pasteData = item.text.tostring()`.

Is the sample code wrong?

**Sample Code**

```
var clipboard = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
var pasteData: String = ""

val item = clipboard.primaryClip.getItemAt(0)

// Gets the clipboard as text.
pasteData = item.text  // It's Wrong, I have to use pasteData = item.text.tostring()
```

**Source Code**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the code, you'll notice that `.text` returns a CharSequence. Here's the issue:

- String inherits from CharSequence
- The method returns a CharSequence

  - But not necessarily a String

As in, `text` can return any CharSequence, not necessarily a String. As a result, this isn't a good idea:

```
pasteData = item.text as String
```

Because it will throw a ClassCastException if the CharSequence isn't a String.

This is where `.toString()` comes in. It converts the CharSequence to an actual String. In addition, there are two other options:

1. `String.valueOf`: `pasteData = String.valueOf(item.text)`
2. `StringBuilder`: `pasteData = StringBuilder().append(item.text).toString()`.

The reasoning behind this lies in inheritance. Consider this:

```
fun someFunction (arg: Int) : CharSequence {
    if(arg < 0) return "This is a String";
    return SomeCustomCharSequenceImpl("Inheritance", 42);
}
```

Now, if you invoke this:

```
val string: String = someFunction(Random().nextInt()); // The random init is not memory efficient, but it's just for a complete demo
```

It will not compile, because a CharSequence isn't necessarily a String. The method works because a String is a CharSequence. If you want it as a String, you can convert it to one using one of the three options above.

Alternatively, if you want to cast it, you could always use `is`, but that means any other implementations of CharSequence will not do what you expect it to; you wouldn't get the String you need.

---

I'm honestly not sure why it uses `.text` directly in the documentation. Might be a bug, or the API might have changed from String to CharSequence. Either way, you need to convert it.

**TL;DR:** Yes, the docs are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It might be wrong in real world because we can have a lot of types from clipboard. But in this sample, they already note (at number 3): "The following snip tests this, but it only show code for handling plain text".